# Destroy and recreate DataTable

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am working on DataTabels.I need to destroy a DataTable and recreate another DataTable. I am using below code.

**HTML Code**

```
<table id="overview" class="table responsive theme-border p-20 ">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th class="all">{{ __('Property') }}</th>
                                <th class="all">{{ __('Unit') }}</th>
                                <th class="all">{{ __('Issue Date') }}</th>
                                <th class="all">{{ __('Expiry Date') }}</th>
                                <th class="all">{{ __('Certified by') }}</th>
                                <th class="all">{{ __('Status') }}</th>
                                <th class="all">{{ __('Certificate') }}</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                    </table>
```

**jQuery Code**

```
$('#overview').DataTable({
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    pageLength: 100,
    responsive: true,
    ajax: $('#getOverviewRoute').val(),
    order: [1, 'desc'],
    ordering: false,
    autoWidth: false,
    drawCallback: function () {
        $(".dataTables_length select").addClass("form-select form-select-sm");
    },
    language: {
        'paginate': {
            'previous': '<span class="iconify" data-icon="icons8:angle-left"></span>',
            'next': '<span class="iconify" data-icon="icons8:angle-right"></span>'
        }
    },
    columns: [
        {
            "data": "property_id",
        },
        {
            "data": "unit_id",
        },
        {
            "data": "issue_date",
        },
        {
            "data": "expiry_date",
        },
        {
            "data": "certified_by",
        },
        {
            "data": "reminder",
        },
        {
            "data": "image",
        },
    ]
});




$(document).on('change', '#time', function () {
    if ($.fn.DataTable.isDataTable('#overview')) {
        $('#overview').DataTable().destroy(true);
    }

    time = $('#time').val();

    $('#overview').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        pageLength: 100,
        responsive: true,
        ajax: {
            url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/owner/safety/timeOverview/' + time, 
            type: 'GET',
        },
        order: [1, 'desc'],
        ordering: false,
        autoWidth: false,
        drawCallback: function () {
            $(".dataTables_length select").addClass("form-select form-select-sm");
        },
        language: {
            'paginate': {
                'previous': '<span class="iconify" data-icon="icons8:angle-left"></span>',
                'next': '<span class="iconify" data-icon="icons8:angle-right"></span>'
            }
        },
        columns: [
            {
                "data": "property_id",
            },
            {
                "data": "unit_id",
            },
            {
                "data": "issue_date",
            },
            {
                "data": "expiry_date",
            },
            {
                "data": "certified_by",
            },
            {
                "data": "reminder",
            },
            {
                "data": "image",
            },
        ]
    });
});
```

But I am getting error `Uncaught TypeError: a is undefined`.

[image]

Comment: What is line #180 in `overview.js`? Futhermore you should add errors as text and not as an image...

Comment: It's possible that `'../owner/safety/timeOverview/' + time` is not returning the value(s)/html that you're expecting and/or that the columns don't match in either of the setups.

Comment: Thanks @DarkBee. If I remove `if ($.fn.DataTable.isDataTable('#overview')) {
        $('#overview').DataTable().destroy(true);
    }` then the error is not showing.

Comment: Thanks @freedomn-m. If I remove `if ($.fn.DataTable.isDataTable('#overview')) {
        $('#overview').DataTable().destroy(true);
    }` then the error is not showing. `'../owner/safety/timeOverview/' + time` is returning expecting HTML, I tested it.

Comment: @DarkBee, This code is in line #180 `$('#overview').DataTable().destroy(true);`.